# Acer Predator dual boot win 11 and ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows, acer

I have recently bought an Acer Predator Triton 300 SE, 12 gen intel, win 11 and I have tried dual booting it according to all the information I can find online.

I have disabled secure boot, set up a supervisor password. However, I could not find the SATA mode even though I hit crtl-s. I tried to go ahead with the dual boot but ubuntu could not detect my SSD (as I did not change the SATA mode to AHCI).

After I stopped the installation and went back to bios to look at things, the next moment when i tried to restart my laptop with F10, it got stuck at a black screen which i suspect is a boot loop. I have not found any solution online regarding dual booting a new Acer Predator laptop, which may have some differences compared to the older models.

Help needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to dual boot for acer predator triton series, the steps are as follows:

1. From windows, run msconfig and go to safe mode, then restart laptop
2. Hit F2 when predator logo is shown and enter bios mode
3. Hit F1 to go to advance options, go to main and press crtl + s
4. VMD controller option will pop-up, disable it, save and exit.
5. As laptop restarts, immediately plug in ubuntu thumbdrive
6. Install as usual.
7. Restart laptop and go to windows
8. Exit safe mode

However, it seems to me that acer 2022 laptops are not compatible with 18.04, as the wifi, trackpad, sound and brightness control are not working. I have some issues with sudo apt-get update & upgrade too.

I would love to use 18.04 but it seems to me that it isn't supported as of now. If anyone has any idea on how to get 18.04 working please let me know!

Thank you!